# Flash not working in IE8, inside of HTML5 video Tag

Tags: flash, html, video, internet-explorer-8

```
<video controls="controls" poster="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/video/General_Ledger_Demo.jpg" width="854" height="480"  onclick="if(/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent))this.play();" autoplay>
            <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/video/General_Ledger_Demo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/video/General_Ledger_Demo.webm" type="video/webm" />
            <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/video/General_Ledger_Demo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/video/General_Ledger_Demo.swf" width="854" height="480" style="position:relative;">
              <param name="movie" value="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/video/General_Ledger_Demo.swf" />
              <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
              <param name="flashVars" value="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;loop=true&amp;src=General_Ledger_Demo.mp4" />
              <embed src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/video/General_Ledger_Demo.swf" width="854" height="480" style="position:relative;"  flashVars="autoplay=true&amp;controls=true&amp;loop=true&amp;poster=<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/video/General_Ledger_Demo.jpg&amp;src=General_Ledger_Demo.mp4"    allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
              <img alt="insight-commercial" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/video/General_Ledger_Demo.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0;" width="854" height="480" title="Video playback is not supported by your browser" />
            </object>
          </video>
```

Works in IE9, Firefox, Safari and even Android Tablets. However, IE8 produces a blank screen (falling back to flash).  The file paths are correct and it is not a permissions issue (all are 755). Been messing with this for days, finally resorting to ask the experts.

Thanks.

Comment: Actual URL: <a href="http://oracle.insightsoftware.com/product/general-ledger-demo-video/">oracle.insightsoftware.com/product/general-ledger-demo</a>

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a .swf file is supposed to be inside a `<video>` tag. I would try an `<object>` tag, with a `type` attribute set to `"application/x-shockwave-flash"` .